Docker swarm (compose file): bind path is not exist. But bind is not declared for such directory
Seems like docker tries to bind all directories under docker in root:
/* SRC FILES */
docker/
  deploy/
    service.yml
  volume/
    redis/.gitkeep
    logs/.gitkeep

I was unabled to find any information about automatic bind under such directory or find such setting in compose or gitlab ci
Unfortunally, I can't show full configuration, but here config, ci and error message at least:
# .gitlab-ci.yml

# Already checked, include files just build and perform php related actions, no docker or env vars involved
include:
  - project: project/repository
    file: "deploy/php-ci.yml"

stages:
  - build
  - test
  - release

variables:
  IMAGE: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
  PROJECT_CODE: "service-2"
  PROJECT_NAMESPACE: "service-2"

cache:
  paths:
    - vendor/
    - node_modules/

branch-build:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'stage'
      when: always
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'main'
      when: always
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
      when: always
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'devops'
      when: always

unit-test:
  stage: test
  image: $IMAGE
  allow_failure: false
  needs:
    - branch-build
  variables:
    ELASTIC_HOST: "elasticsearch.logs:9300"
    ELASTIC_LOGS_INDEX: "test_service_api"
  before_script:
    - COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1 composer install --dev --no-interaction
    - cp .env.example .env
    - php artisan key:generate
  script:
    - php artisan test
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'main'
      when: always
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'stage'
      when: always
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'merge_request_event'
      when: always
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'devops'
      when: always

prod-deploy:
  needs:
    - branch-build
    - unit-test
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'main'
      when: always

stage-deploy:
  needs:
    - branch-build
    - unit-test
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'stage'
      when: always

# Mine written
devops-deploy:
  stage: release
  environment: staging
  needs:
    - branch-build
    - unit-test
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
    - cp $ENV_STAGING ./docker/deploy/.env
    - cat ./docker/deploy/.env
  script:
    - docker stack deploy -c ./docker/deploy/wizard.yml --with-registry-auth wizard
  tags:
    - swarm-stage
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == 'devops'
      when: always

# service.yml

version: "3.8"

services:
  app:
    image: ${IMAGE}
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 1s
      update_config:
        failure_action: rollback
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
    networks:
      - proxy_main
      - apiats-swarm-internal
    ports:
      - "8090:80"
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      # Explicit volume creation \ binding, no deploy directory here
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - ./docker/volumes/logs:/var/logs
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wizard-api-app.rule=Host(`service.local`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.wizard-api-app.entrypoints=web"

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
        delay: 1s
      update_config:
        failure_action: rollback
        parallelism: 1
        delay: 10s
    ports:
      - "8025"
    networks:
      - swarm-internal

networks:
  proxy_main:
    external: true
  swarm-internal:
    external: true

FROM php:8.2.15-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip \
    supervisor \
    zlib1g-dev

ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd opcache iconv

RUN unlink /etc/localtime
RUN ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Moscow /etc/localtime

ENV LOG_CHANNEL=stderr

RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pecl install redis &&  docker-php-ext-enable redis

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

WORKDIR /var/www/html

COPY *.json *.lock ./
COPY . .
COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /docker-entrypoint.sh
COPY ./.build/supervisor.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/ss.conf
RUN cp "/var/www/html/.build/php.ini" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

RUN composer check-platform-reqs \
       && COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1 composer install \
           --no-dev \
           --prefer-dist \
           --no-scripts \
           --optimize-autoloader \
           --no-interaction \
       && composer clear-cache

RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]

I tried to remove include, but seems like problem somewhere in another place

Sorry, here is error message:
stage-swarm-manager-01   Shutdown        Rejected 4 seconds ago            "invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /builds/project/service-2.0/docker/deploy"


Docker swarm really only supports absolute bind paths, and the path needs to pre-exist on all swarm nodes where the service might be scheduled - so if you have more than 1 node its up to you to ensure the path is valid on other nodes.

@ChrisBecke, I know this, but I can't really understand what is going on here, since it is not clear for me, where we have such bind instruction

Both your volume mounts are bind mounts: "./:/var/www/html", "./docker/volumes/logs:/var/logs
